# How to append individual rows to one dataframe with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is printing individual rows and I need for all of my rows to be appended or concatenated into one dataframe.  Here is an example of my hrly_df dataframe. Each row has index 0, which means it is being added individually. I haven't been able to figure out what needs to be changed in my code below.  I would like for my output to look something like this

**Desire Output**

```
    field id |   HourlyPrecipIn | HourlyRH | HourlyTempF | dateTime
0   40238        0.00             98         56.5          2019-05-22 01:00:00 
1   40238        0.01             95         55.5          2019-05-22 02:00:00 
2   40238        0.02             96         57.7          2019-05-22 03:00:00
```

**Current Output**

`HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF             dateTime field id
0             0.0      98.8         44.9  2019-05-22 01:00:00    40238
   HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF             dateTime field id
0             0.0      98.9         45.1  2019-05-22 02:00:00    40238
   HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF             dateTime field id
0             0.0      98.7         45.1  2019-05-22 03:00:00    40238
   HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF             dateTime field id
0            0.02      99.6         45.3  2019-05-22 04:00:00    40238
   HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF             dateTime field id
0             0.0      95.0         46.7  2019-05-22 05:00:00    40238`

**Code:**

```
`for lat, lon, id_, in zip(latval, lonval, idVal):

                    print 'Starting import of field id: {0}'.format(id_)
                    time_param = '?start='+ config.dayVal +'T'+ '06:00:00' + 'Z' + '&end='+ config.todayVal+ 'T'+ '05:00'+'Z'

                    #########HOURLY VALUES############
                    hrTemp = 'https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-temperature/' + str(lat)+'/' + str(lon) + time_param + '&unit=fahrenheit'
                    hrHumidity =  'https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-relative-humidity/' + str(lat)+'/' + str(lon) + time_param
                    hrPrecip = 'https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/' + str(lat)+'/' + str(lon) + time_param + '&unit=inches'


                    resp_pre_hr = se_.get(hrPrecip, auth=(config.dtn_app_id, config.dtn_key), timeout=30)
                    resp_temp_hr = se_.get(hrTemp, auth=(config.dtn_app_id, config.dtn_key), timeout=60)
                    resp_rh_hr = se_.get(hrHumidity, auth=(config.dtn_app_id, config.dtn_key), timeout=90)

                    preValHrly = json.loads(resp_pre_hr.content)
                    tempValHrly = json.loads(resp_temp_hr.content)
                    humidityHrly = json.loads(resp_rh_hr.content)

                    logging.info (hrHumidity)
                    logging.info (humidityHrly)

                    aHumidVal = humidityHrly['series']
                    aPreVal =  preValHrly['series']
                    aTempVal = tempValHrly['series']
                    aTimeVal = tempValHrly['series']


                    for aHumidValJ, aTempValJ, aPreValJ, aTimeJ in zip (aHumidVal, aTempVal , aPreVal, aTimeVal):
                        aHumidVJ = aHumidValJ['value']
                        aTempVJ =  aTempValJ['value']
                        aPreVJ = aPreValJ['value']
                        aTimeVJ = aTimeJ['validTime']
                        aTimeVJ = aTimeVJ[:-1]
                        aTimeVJ = aTimeVJ.replace("T", " ")

                        from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
                        to_zone = tz.gettz('America/Chicago') 
                        utc = datetime.strptime(aTimeVJ, DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
                        utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
                        central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
                        t = central.strftime(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)



                        hrly_df= pd.DataFrame({'dateTime' :[t], 'field id': [id_], 'HourlyPrecipIn': [aPreVJ],'HourlyRH' : [aHumidVJ], 'HourlyTempF' : [aTempVJ]})
```

Comment: You can use ```pandas.concat``` to combine multiple dataframes into one

Comment: have you considered setting your `dateTime` column as the index?

Comment: Please format the second table with \`\`\` something \`\`\` -> ```something```

Comment: @jeschwar, the issue is not the index, it's that each row comes in individually.

Comment: @gwest then use `pd.concat` as suggested by @iamchoosinganame.  I would create an empty list before your for-loops start and append your `hrly_df` objects to this list.  Then after the for-loops finish use `pd.concat` on your populated list to get the desired output.